# Generalization of two formulae and an alternative proof of Bretschneider's formula

Tags: geometry, reference-request, area, quadrilateral

[image]Below I present two seemingly unknown identities that I then use to provide an alternative proof of Bretschneider's formula. Made the necessary adjustments, the identities can also be used to provide alternative proofs of Brahmagupta's Formula as well as Heron's Formula (see for example https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/07/killing-three-birds-with-one-stone.html). For implications in a triangle see also https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html.

Here, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are the sides of a general convex quadrilateral, $s$ is the semiperimeter, and $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are two opposite angles. Then

$$\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{(s-a)(s-d)-bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{ad}\quad and \quad \cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)-bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{ad}\tag{1}$$

**Proof**. By the Law of Cosines,

$$a^2+d^2-2ad\cos{\alpha}=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos{\gamma}\tag{2}$$

Yielding $\cos{\alpha}=\frac{a^2+d^2-b^2-c^2+2bc\cos{\gamma}}{2ad}$. Now, making use of the half angle formula for cosine,

$$\begin{align*} \cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}&=\frac{a^2+d^2+2ad-b^2-c^2+2bc\cos{\gamma}}{4ad}\tag{3}\\ &=\frac{a^2+d^2+2ad-b^2-c^2+2bc(1-2\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}})}{4ad}\tag{4}\\&=\frac{(a+d)^2-(b-c)^2-4bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{4ad}\tag{5}\\&=\frac{(a+d+b-c)(a+d-b+c)-4bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{4ad}\tag{6}\\&=\frac{1}{ad}\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}-c\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}-b\right)-\frac{bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{ad}\tag{7}\\&=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)-bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{ad}\tag{8}\end{align*}$$

$\square$

The other formula can be obtained similarly by replacing $\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ by $1 - \sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ in $(3)$.

**A proof of Bretschneider's formula**

The formulae in $(1)$ can be rewritten as follows

$$ad\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=(s-a)(s-d)\tag{9}$$

and

$$bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+ad\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=(s-b)(s-c)\tag{10}$$

Multiplying $(9)$ and $(10)$ we get

$$\begin{align*}\left(ad\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\right)\left(bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+ad\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right) &= (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)\tag{11}\end{align*}$$

Expanding, factorizing, completing the squares and keeping in mind some well-known trigonometric identities,

$$\begin{align*}abcd\cos^2\left({\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{2}}\right)+\left(ad\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\sin{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\cos{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\right)^2 &=(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)\tag{12}\\abcd\cos^2\left({\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{2}}\right)+\left(\frac{ad\sin{\alpha}}{2}+\frac{bc\sin{\gamma}}{2}\right)^2 &=(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)\tag{13}
\end{align*}$$

Since the area of $ABCD$ can be expressed as the sum of the areas of $\triangle{ABD}$ and $\triangle{CBD}$, which in turn can be written as $\frac{ad\sin{\alpha}}{2}+\frac{bc\sin{\gamma}}{2}$, then we are done.
$\square$

Are the identities (9) and (10) known? Is this proof of Bretschneider's formula known? Thanks in advance.

**Edited**: I have added a concept map of identities (9) and (10) so you can see clearly what's going on here.

Comment: Please, accompany the votes down with a justification. It is much more useful.

Comment: I upvoted, but I think it would be preferable if you could put the equations in the blog post in this question since the blog post isn't very long.

Comment: @Casimir Done! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The result, which I think looks best in the form of $(9)$ and $(10)$, is very nice! I suspect it's not new, however. It seems like the kind of thing that would appear as an exercise in older trigonometry books ... from the era when printers still had to hand-write the "$\alpha$"s and "$\gamma$"s and such. :) Trig books covered a broader range of esoteric stuff back then. ... If that happens to be the case, then it's worth remembering that someone discovering a result before you is —in the words of Steve Fisk— "merely an accident of Time"; it doesn't diminish your personal accomplishment.

Comment: As a stylistic point for the proof of your results: I would've started with the nicely-balanced $(2)$ and simply substituted $\cos\alpha\to 2\cos^2(\alpha/2)-1$ on the left and $\cos\gamma\to1-2\sin^2(\gamma/2)$ on the right (or vice-versa). The symbol manipulation becomes much cleaner —you can probably even skip much (most? all?) of it, since your audience presumably knows how to expand and factor simple polynomials— and avoids the unnecessarily-cumbersome formatted fractions. ... It also invites consideration of performing "matching" half-angle substitutions on both sides.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your always valuable comments.

Comment: In private communication, Martin Josefsson, whom I consider an authority on these issues, wrote "... I cannot say that I remember seeing the identities (4) and (5) anywhere else before." Referring to identities (9) and (10) of this post. Then he adds "Even though much has already been written about these formulas, the ideas for proving Bretschneider 'formula and the area of ​​a bicentric quadrilateral are novel as far as I know."

Comment: I have organized my ideas presented here (and related links) and put it in a draft paper which you can download here: https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/10/two-identities-and-their-consequences.html